# iPhone enterprise deployment

Tags: iphone, deployment

I am building an app using the apple "in-house" deployment of the enterprise program. But I want to distribute this app free of cost to few non member of enterprise. we cannot make those person an employee of the organization because of some company policy. Is this possible and is there any legal issues associated on apple side with this kind of distribution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would Ad Hoc distribution work for your purposes? It does, I believe, require periodic updates of provisioning profile. Also, it would require having UDIDs for the few non-members' iDevices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to do some digging into Apple's policy, but I'm pretty sure I read that the Enterprise Deployment method is strictly for in-house employees. In order to distribute to outside individuals, you may have to go on the App Store.

Unless you could have the company those individuals work for sign up for the Enterprise Deployment program and distribute it internally there?

To be safe, check with Apple

Answer (score 0):

Some companies have both Enterprise and regular developer accounts.  They use the regular developer account for giving Ad Hoc apps to "beta testers", or for submitting suitable apps to the public App store.